# TypeError:is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, prototype

i am using [tracking.js](https://trackingjs.com/) and i want to create a [customTracker](https://trackingjs.com/docs.html#trackers) so:

```
var CustomTracker = function(){
  CustomTracker(this, 'constructor');
}

CustomTracker.prototype.track = function(pixel, width, height){

  var results = ['foo'];

  this.emit('track', {
      data: results
  });
}

tracking.inherits(CustomTracker, tracking.Tracker);

var myTracker = new tracking.CustomTracker

myTracker.on('track', function(event) {
  console.log('Event: ', event);
});

tracking.track('#myVideo', myTracker);
```

But Console says:

> Uncaught TypeError: tracking.CustomTracker is not a constructor

Where is the problem. I dont understand why?

Comment: I think your issue lies here `var CustomTracker = function(){
  CustomTracker(this, 'constructor');
}`

Comment: you aren't invoking the constructor.  Try `var myTracker = new tracking.CustomTracker()`.  (note the missing parens).

Answer (score 0):

Try this (from documentation):

```
var MyTracker = function() {
    MyTracker(this, 'constructor');
}

tracking.inherits(MyTracker, tracking.Tracker);

var MyTracker = function() {
    MyTracker.prototype.track = function(pixels, width, height) {
        // Your code here

        this.emit('track', {
            // Your results here
        });
    }
}

var myTracker = new tracking.MyTracker();

myTracker.on('track', function(event) {
    // Results are inside the event
});

tracking.track('#myVideo', myTracker);
```

Comment: this is *almost exactly* the code that was included in the original question, with the exception of the missing parens, which I mentioned in a comment.

Comment: Same Error with parens. :-( the example from documentation does not work too